# Is picosecond timer possible?

Tags: c, timer, cpu, clock, high-resolution-clock

**Given**

I want to make a device, that measures distance, based on the time electromagnetic wave passes from one point (computer\microcontroller) to other. I do not consider phase shift method for that.

I want centimeter precision (at least).

For that purpose, both computers should have clock with at least 33.3 ps period resolution.

If consider clock as a counter loop, that just increments `uint64_t` variable each time, I need that loop do each iteration 30 billions time per second with 33.3 ps pause.

**Problem**

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52082768/9430073), commentators and user, who answered states, that CPU performance is limited by its sizes due to the fact, that information can't propagates faster, than speed of light. It makes sense.

**Thoughts**

However, there is the [CPUs millions instructions per second table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instructions_per_second#Timeline_of_instructions_per_second).

Let's consider, Intel Core i5-11600K: it has 6 cores and 346 350 MIPS at 4.92 GHz. Obviously, 345 billions instructions are for multithreading program (or even not?), however, per one core it should be 346/6 = 57 000 MIPS.

57 000 MIPS means 57 billions instructions per second per one core, and period equals about 17 ps.

Electromagnetic wave passes 5 mm per 17ps.

Threadreaper has 36 trillions instructions per core, which means 8 um wave propagation at all.

So, by that logic it all should not work, however works. What is the trick? Does picosecond timer yet possible?

---

## Update

If You are going to use multithreading as an argument, please, in the table I provided above, look at Intel Core 2 Extreme X6800, that has only 2 cores and 27 000 MIPS, i.e. 13 500 MIPS per core, which is still pretty fast, and should be impossible (light will pass only 2.3 cm).

Comment: You'll only get an accurate clock from a loop if that's the only thing the CPU is doing, which is very unlikely. Use a hardware counter.

Comment: @WeatherVane, about CPU I have some thoughts on it. It will be perfect, if You can provide some counter ICs with at least 30 Ghz frequency

Comment: Short answer: No, you can't with standard CPU's. Maybe you want explore the latest ST microelettronics "Time of Flight" technology: https://www.st.com/en/imaging-and-photonics-solutions/time-of-flight-sensors.html

Comment: @Frankie_C, it would be a pleasure to read Your full answer

Comment: Analog phase detectors are used to measure such times.

Comment: @dimich, as I wrote in the post beginning, that method is not acceptable

Comment: Well, it may be unacceptable, but that's how it is done when you see a device doing it. That is why a laser meter doesn't emit an invisible ping of 1 ns (which would be even way too long if the idea was just to measure how many times it takes to go forth to the wall and back to then sensor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you ever visited a factory? Let's say a car factory.

It passes through many different stages. Some workers are painting the bodywork, then it has to dry, then some other workers mount the wheels, some others add the seats, etc, etc.

A Tesla (just use that example, because the data are public) takes 12 weeks to go through the entire process (it takes 12 weeks between the moment the fabrication is started and the moment the working car exist the factory).

Yet, Tesla build 1000 cars per day

It would be a mistake to say 1/(12*7)=0.0119 cars per day.
Or, on the contrary to expect that if a factory build 1000 cars per day, that means that a car is build in 86.4 seconds.

And that is not just because of threads, or parallelism. Likewise, with my examples, one could say "but a factory doesn't build 1000 cars a day, there are more than one Tesla factories". Indeed, there are 6 of them. So 6 threads if you will.
Still, it would be a mistake to deduce that it takes 518 seconds (86.4×6) to build a Tesla, not 12 weeks.
It is also because of the process itself: the worker who is painting the bodywork is painting the one of a second car, while another worker is mounting the wheels of the first car. It takes time for a car to propagate through the whole chain. The computation `86400/1000*6` would be valid only if one worker was working at the same time (nobody takes care of the wheels while the car is being painted, or while it dries).

So, no, you can't deduce the length of an instruction from the number of instructions per second. No more that you can deduce the time it takes to build a Tesla (12 weeks) from the rate at which the factories produce them (1000/6 per day and factory).

(I could have used many other analogy. For example, since you are mentioning a signal propagation: you may know that it takes hours for an electron, when you switch on the light, to goes from the switch you've just closed to the lightbulb. Yet some quintillions of them pass through the lightbuld per second :D

Answer (score 2):

As others have commented, you can't expect any CPU to complete a loop iteration in 33 picoseconds.

To address your confusion:

> 57 000 MIPS means 57 billions instructions per second per one core, and period equals about 17 ps.

57,000 MIPS *does not* mean that the CPU can retire 57e9 instructions per second. The MIPS is mostly meaningless, because it compares to the VAX Unit of performance. IOW, the CPU can retire an equivalent of 57,000 VAX instructions per second.

It's more useful to look at the clock. At 5GHz, a *single* clock cycle takes 200 picoseconds, and no instruction actually takes a single clock cycle -- they all take multiple (but due to pipelining, you may be able to *retire* one instruction / cycle).

Comment: Can You please add more details on VAX and pipelining? As I understand, MIPS refers to CPU instructions, like `PUSH` or `MOV`. If 57 billions of MIPS, i.e. `MOV` (for example) instructions are indeed done in 1 second, than statement about 5 GHz and more than one instruction per second is wrong. I understand that some instruction indeed, can take more than one cycle

Comment: @bcubeu26dncs If 9 women gave birth to 9 children in 9 month, their performance is 1 children/month. But it doesn't mean 9 women can give birth to 1 children in 1 month.

Comment: 1) Are You better in women, than CPUs? Otherwise, I do not understand why You used analogy instead of direct answer.
2) So, from Your analogy, as I understand, You mean, that I can have desired number of instructions per second due to multithreading?
3) Argument about multithreading seems to be wrong, due to Intel Core 2 Extreme X6800 (2-core) that has 27 000 MIPS, i.e. 13 500 MIPS per core, that is still to high and should be impossible, according to You

Comment: @bcubeu26dncs You really need to read up on multiscalar and pipelined CPUs and instruction level parallelism (multithreading has _nothing_ to with this).

Comment: As for multithreading, this is what I assume You meant by Your analogy, otherwise it wrong. As for You write now, I am not specialist on it, but as I understand it means, that CPU can do more than 1 instruction at once. Anyway, I will read information on it, thanks

Comment: @bcubeu26dncs: A 5GHz CPU has a clock period of 200 ps.  Being able to run 4 instructions per clock cycle means they happen *in parallel* overlapping during that 200 ps, not that they run one after the other to subdivide that 200 ps clock period. (https://www.lighterra.com/papers/modernmicroprocessors/ is excellent).  Besides that, I/O takes vastly longer than 1 clock cycle, and `rdtsc` takes about 20 clock cycles.  It's completely impossible to poll an I/O pin even once per 200 ps on a modern x86 using just CPU instructions.

Comment: @PeterCordes, I think the main problem is that increment operation can't be parallelized, as I understand, so number of cores does not make any sense, when I need to increment same variable. Yeah, I have read about `rdtsc`, however if it takes constant time to execute it, I can just subtract that value. But You also correct as for I/O performance, however, I think it is still has sense to test it

Comment: @bcubeu26dncs: Right, multiple cores won't help.  But like I said, multiple instructions per cycle on a single core won't help either.  Two or three (cached) loads per clock cycle are possible on modern CPUs, but they all read cache at the same time, not 3 different times within the clock period.  (L1d cache is multi-ported so 3 different reads can happen in parallel.)  Off-core traffic takes way longer.  Yeah you might possibly factor out most of the variability in `rdtsc` and stuff, but at *best* you have 200 ps precision on a 5GHz i7.  Probably much worse due to ring bus variability.

Comment: I think the whole thread can be zipped to the @PeterCordes statement, that in multicore case instructions run simultaneously at one time, and not divide the clock period, that, probably was my misconception

Answer (score 0):

A 5GHz CPU has a clock period of 200 ps.  One core being able to run 4 to 6 instructions per clock cycle means they happen in parallel overlapping during that 200 ps, not that they run one after the other to subdivide that 200 ps clock period. ([Modern Microprocessors
A 90-Minute Guide!](https://lighterra.com/papers/modernmicroprocessors) is excellent for an intro to superscalar CPU pipelines).

(Multiple cores don't help either; their clocks aren't necessarily even in phase with each other or at the same clock speed, although Intel client (non-server) CPUs do tie all the cores to the same frequency at least for non-turbo.  And they're certainly independent of each other in terms of executing instructions.)

Two or three (cached) loads per clock cycle are possible on modern CPUs, but they all read cache at the same time, not 3 different times within the clock period. (L1d cache is multi-ported so 3 different reads can happen in parallel, along with a write.)  Off-core traffic takes way longer.

---

Besides that, I/O takes vastly longer than 1 clock cycle.   It's completely impossible to poll an I/O pin even once per 200 ps on a modern x86 using just CPU instructions.  Traffic between a core and any I/O pin has to go over a ring bus which connects all the cores, the memory controllers, and the "system agent" (where the PCIe lanes connect).  Due to contention, there can be variability in latency there.  And the fastest off-chip connections are the PCI-express lanes, which are much slower than 5GHz.

You might possibly factor out most of the variability in `rdtsc` and stuff (which takes about 20 clock cycles), but at best you have 200 ps precision on a 5GHz i7 even if you could factor out all the I/O timing variability and do I/O at the frequency of a CPU core.

In practice it'd be much less precise.